# How can a child with one Chinese parent but with a French passport leave China?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china, chinese-citizens, french-citizens

My son has one parent who is Chinese, but he has only a French passport in which he has an exit/entry permit for China which his father got for him. However, according to the father, the child cannot go back to France because of his residence permit.

Which document should we use at the airport leaving China and going to France, the French passport?

Can we cross the border without having problems with immigration and security control?H

Comment: I've edited to make it a bit clearer but, if I've misunderstood, I apologize. Could you clarify: who has a residence permit and for what country? Is the Chinese parent (the father?) saying that Chinese authorities will not allow the child to leave China?

Comment: Why or how does the residence permit prevent the child from going to France?

Comment: I believe most countries require their citizens to use their (as opposed to other countries') passports when entering/exiting, so if the son is a Chinese citizen he would have to obtain and use a Chinese passport.

Comment: @fkraiem: A Chinese dual national, like the OP's child, should *not* use a Chinese passport. They should instead use a Chinese Travel Document to enter and exit China or a Chinese Entry/Exit Permit to exit China (in combination with their foreign passport). If they use a Chinese passport with a foreign passport, they may find themselves not allowed to exit China.

Answer (score 5):

The father's explanation doesn't hold water and makes no sense. However just in case I [ran the search on Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=FR&NV=France&AC=CN&AV=China&DC=FR&DV=France&h=b389e7b2de6e7de31e76949a134988461962571c) which doesn't confirm this either:

> Nationality   France
>
> Foreign resident of China
>
> Destination  France
>
> Passport
>
> Passport required.

So nothing special seem to be required.